# Generate jar with sources

Tags: java, jar

I am using the Java Tool Providers compiler and compile some source code into a `jar` something like this:

```
JarOutputStream target = new JarOutputStream(jarstream, manifest);
String name = source.getPath(); //.class file
JarEntry entry = new JarEntry(name);
entry.setTime(source.lastModified());
target.putNextEntry(entry);
target.closeEntry();
...
```

I would like to generate another jar for the source `.java` files.

Can I do it the same way as adding `.class` files into the `jar`?

Comment: Yes, of course, and you aren't using he compiler at all in this code, only the JarOutputStream. Clarify your thinking.

Comment: I only wanted to say that the compiled files (.class) for the jar have been compiled by the javax.compiler during runtime just to avoid any missunderstandings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, we make two jars : one for compiled classes (.class files) and one another for source code (.java files). You can proceed with same method, but in both cases, files must be under directories according to the package declaration in source code.